# How to Properly Set Up custom Event

Tags: java, events, javafx, event-handling, custom-events

OK - I've fought and fought with this and read a million posts, tutorials, etc. None of them seem to address directly what I'm trying to do here. I've got this little code example to illustrate.

Basically, I want to be able to raise/fire a custom event from the button and have the label respond to that event.

(Please note that I AM NOT INTERESTED in finding other ways to do it than what I'm trying to do here with the actual Event objects. I know perfectly well how to do it with change listeners and such, but I want to learn how to do it this way.)

Here is the code, which you can see doesn't get me the result I'm looking for. Much of it comes from some examples (that didn't really work for me) and I admit there's parts here that are going "whoosh" over my head.

If someone can help me get it working, I can dissect it later to make sure I understand what is going on exactly. Here's the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // label that should receive the event and react to it
    MyLabel lblReceiver = new MyLabel("And I Should Receive & React");

    // button to firs the event
    Button btnSender = new Button("Initate Event");
    btnSender.setPrefWidth(200);
    btnSender.setOnAction(e -> {
        MyEvent.fireEvent(lblReceiver, e); // really confused what the first parameter here is supposed to be.
    });

    // set up stage and show it
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    VBox root = new VBox(btnSender, lblReceiver);
    root.setSpacing(10);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

// Interface for objects that want to listen to my event
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
interface MyEventListener {
    void onMyEvent();
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

// My event definition itself
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyEvent extends Event {

    public static final EventType<MyEvent> MY_EVENT = new EventType<>(ANY, "MY_EVENT");

    public MyEvent(EventType<? extends MyEvent> eventType) {
    super(eventType);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

//base/parent class for my label - this is what should receive/respond to event and
// where I'm sure i have problems - just don't know what.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyLabel extends Label implements MyEventListener {

    public MyLabel(String name) {
    this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    this.setText(name);
    this.setPrefWidth(200);
    }

    @Override // this is what I'm expecting to happen when i click the button
    public void onMyEvent() {
    this.setText("YAY! i got the event!");
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super MyEvent>> onMyEventProp
        = new SimpleObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super MyEvent>>(this, "onMyEvent") {
    @Override
    protected void invalidated() {
        setEventHandler(MyEvent.MY_EVENT, get());
    }
    };

    public final void setOnMyEvent(EventHandler<? super MyEvent> handler) {
    onMyEventProp.set(handler);
    }

    public final EventHandler<? super MyEvent> getOnMyEvent() {
    return onMyEventProp.get();
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<EventHandler<? super MyEvent>> onMyEventProperty() {
    return onMyEventProp;
    }

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

You seem have everything set up correctly except for two problems.

1. You never add an `EventHandler` that listens for your event.

   Implementing an arbitrary interface will not make your object react to your custom event. The event processing system has no knowledge of your interface and doesn't even know you've implemented it. If you want your `onMyEvent()` method to be invoked when your event reaches the label, you would need to do something like:

   ```
   public MyLabel() {
       //...
       addEventHandler(MyEvent.MY_EVENT, event -> onMyEvent());
   }
   ```

   Note I used `addEventHandler` so that the class itself doesn't rely on the `onMyEvent` property. If you relied on the property then outside code could accidentally break your code by replacing the `EventHandler`.

   This makes me wonder if the `MyEventListener` interface is really necessary. Couldn't you just do what you needed inside the `EventHandler`?
2. You never actually fire an instance of your `MyEvent`.

   You currently have:

   ```
   btnSender.setOnAction(e -> MyEvent.fireEvent(lblReceiver, e));
   ```

   This simply refires `e` (an `ActionEvent`) towards `lblReceiver`. The `fireEvent` method is a `static` method declared by `javafx.event.Event`. Prefixing the method call with `MyEvent` doesn't change what method is actually called here. Change that to the following:

   ```
   btnSender.setOnAction(e -> Event.fireEvent(lblReceiver, new MyEvent()));
   // or...
   btnSender.setOnAction(e -> lblReceiver.fireEvent(new MyEvent()));

   // The second option is a convenience method and simply forwards to Event.fireEvent
   ```

   In order to actually fire an instance of your own event class at your label.

---

### Fundamentals of Event Dispatching

There are two phases to event processing in JavaFX:

- Capturing phase

  - The first phase. Here the event travels from the start of its path down to the target. At each step along the way the appropriate event *filters* are invoked. Filters are added via methods such as `Node.addEventFilter(EventType,EventHandler)`.
- Bubbling phase

  - The second phase. Here the event travels from the target back up to the start of the path. At each step along the way the appropriate event *handlers* are invoked. Handlers are added via methods such as `Node.addEventHandler(EventType,EventHandler)` and via properties such as `Node.onKeyPressed` and `ButtonBase.onAction`.

And event processing consists of the following components:

- [`javafx.event.Event`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/event/Event.html) (and subclasses)

  - The actual object passed around. Carries information related to the event (e.g. the cursor's location for `MouseEvent`s).

    An `Event` also carries the *source*. However, the source is dynamic; it will always be the object the `EventHandler` currently handling the event was added to. So an `EventHandler` added to a `Button` will have the `Button` as the event's source, but the same event will have the parent as it's source for an `EventHandler` added to the parent. This behavior doesn't change even if you used the same `EventHandler` instance both times.
- [`javafx.event.EventType`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventType.html)

  - Refines the meaning of a class of `Event`. For example, a `MouseEvent` with the `MOUSE_PRESSED` type means, unsurprisingly, the mouse was pressed. An `EventType` has a supertype; this forms a hierarchy across *all* types for every kind of event. A handler registered for a supertype will also be notified of subtypes.

    You cannot have two or more `EventType`s with the same supertype and name. This is why instances are typically `public static final` fields of the corresponding event class.
- [`javafx.event.EventHandler`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventHandler.html)

  - Handles any events its registered for. This is a functional interface (can be the target of a lambda expression or method reference). It's implementations of this interface that do the application-level work (i.e. do something when a button is fired).
- [`javafx.event.EventDispatcher`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventDispatcher.html)

  - Responsible for dispatching the event to the appropriate handlers. Each object capable of being the target of an event typically has its own dispatcher. For example, each `Window`, `Scene`, and `Node` instance has its own `EventDispatcher` instance (held in a property).

    *Note: Outside highly specialized situations, you will never have to deal with this interface directly.*
- [`javafx.event.EventDispatchChain`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventDispatchChain.html)

  - Represents the path the event will take when it's fired at a target. Instances of this interface function as a stack of `EventDispatcher`s. When an event is fired, a new chain is created and configured based on the event's target. In the case of the scene graph and the target is a `Node`, the stack consists of the `EventDispatcher`s belonging to the `Window`, the `Scene`, and then each `Node` down to (parent to child) and including the target. The event travels down this chain (the *capturing* phase) and then back up this chain (the *bubbling* phase).

    *Note: You will likely never need to use this interface directly.*
- [`javafx.event.EventTarget`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/event/EventTarget.html)

  - The actual target of the event. The `EventTarget` interface has one method that is used to build the `EventDispatchChain`. In other words, the target determines the path of the event. This is the first argument in `Event.fireEvent(EventTarget,Event)`.

    *Note: You only need to use this interface if you're creating an object that can (obviously) be the target of events (and your object doesn't extend from an implementation of `EventTarget`).*

Comment: Thanks @Slaw! I've got it working now just as i had hoped. I do have one question. How can i (or can i?) decouple the event firing from the event target? That is, is there a way to sort of fire an event into the "air" and anything that happens to be listening for it can react? in other words - so that my "initiator" doesn't have to know about who is actually listening or if anyone is listening at all for that matter?

Comment: JavaFX events are meant to be processed as described above. You might be looking for something [like `EventBus` from Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/package-summary.html), where any old object can be an event. Note, however, that the code posting an event and the code listening for an event must be communicating though _some_ shared object (e.g. an `EventBus`). Even when using something like CDI the container handles the communication.

Comment: LOL! @Slaw Before I saw your response, and anticipating that the FX Events would not let me decouple like i want, I started building my own system for it ... and named my facilitating object "EventBus" ! as it seemed like a service bus for Events to me!